# expanding complex-valued functions in Julia

Tags: python, math, julia, complex-numbers, wolframalpha

In Wolfram Alpha I can use `complex expand sin(x + Iy)` to get back `sin(x) cosh(y) + i cos(x) sinh(y)`. Is there a package in Julia or alternatively Python that does the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Julia`, I find this

```
using SymPy
@syms x,y
sympy.expand_trig( sin(x + im*y) )

#sin(x)⋅cosh(y) + ⅈ⋅cos(x)⋅sinh(y)
```

The similar solution can also be found in the library `SymPy` of `Python`.